# Language Word Checker

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, balanced-string

Develop a program to check if a given word is part of a language defined by the following rules:

- The language has a set of rules.
- The empty string is considered a valid word in the language.
- Two words from the language can be concatenated to create a new word in the language.
- If X is a word in the language, then "A" + X + "A" is also a word in the language.
- If X is a word in the language, then "A" + X + "C" is also a word in the language.
- If X is a word in the language, then "B" + X + "A" is also a word in the language.
- If X is a word in the language, then "B" + X + "C" is also a word in the language.

You can assume all inputs only consist of the characters A, B and C.

Examples:

- The word "CB" doesn't belong to the language. There is no way to arrive at this word from the above rules.
- The word "BAAC" belongs to the language.

  Reasoning: The empty string is a valid word. Applying the "A" + X + "A" rule, we get "AA". Now we apply the "B" + X + "C" rule to get "BAAC".
- The word "BCBC" belongs to the language.

  Reasoning: The empty string is a valid word. Applying the "B" + X + "C" rule, we get "BC". Now we apply the concatenation rule to get "BCBC". The concatenation rule can be used to concatenate a word with itself.

### Test cases

```
CBAA ---> false
CBBB ---> false
BCCA ---> false
CCAC ---> false
ABAC ---> true
ACAB ---> false
AAAC ---> true
BBAC ---> true
CABC ---> false
CCAB ---> false
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) problem. While the language looks random, I hope you can find a pattern in the language to write the shortest code possible. Hint: It is possible to check in linear time.

Comment: Can we assume the input will only consist of these three letters, or do we have to test for and reject other letters?

Comment: Of course! Isn't this the norm for our site? Anyway, I'll edit the question.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure, since this problem is about input validation. It feels different than saying a number will only consist of digits, for example.

Comment: Suggested title: "Accept this funky context-free language". "Language Word Checker" suggests some kind of natlang battery thing.

Comment: Suggested tag: [tag:balanced-string]

Comment: BABA might be a good test case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 16 bytes

```
,UċƤ"⁾CBḤ«ƑJ>LḂ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18n9Ej3sSVKjxr3OTs93LHk0OpjE73sfB7uaFL5/3D3lsPtj5rWRP7/7@zk6Mjl7OTkxOXk7AxkOTs6czk6gQhnRycuR0cgywnEBfKcQbIgMZAwAA)

[Validated against tsh's Python demonstration](https://tio.run/##bVOxbtswEN31FVcVhURUdix3M6ACtoEOQdd2CdKCkE4WHVoUSDqFx3bt1H/I1h/I1CEo8h/pj7hHirbsIIYH8r13d7y7p25nG9W@29dabUBY1FYpaUBsOqUtdFpV29JGnl2jlLsD4y9f8ZbLzJ9FvYuiHqSgleYbKCBJkn326e/Px7v43/c/y8XT/d3D78dfl18@Pt3/2BN7lc9G@XUUVVgDpRJVatgsAvqJGiS2dIU3MIVXBUxmoNFudQsfuDToRQ2XNZUJwosLmHq4VNvWzokwY39Mk3nCBmZxyixOmeUpswwMvSSEve8LKn1Q98ALD3tNUCd5iVALbSykPnAUEjGI53FCQ26tgngR@xBDtek8XitB3YxNJ4VNSZfBeSx7VoBigBuIU1Iq26A2/sqGrGYctClpM6dkA@IKkPgEWQbEx0usLaWY@EvtOm/o2WD6JR3G00BRuLyzXv@2gPzIo/SrrG0gR@ekwRfGF4C@uKvuDcJXGtEcHRJEB9s44WDK9MyKGVwFj5LwmkWR66R1jWjerjCdZJDnGUzZjAZ76W1ulNxaoVqwWtwK7iCNayytAVVVznIr25iMdNDSH7ECWmbZYHlznNU3pStXJHxFZMPFMsnc5pC7qbZsGCM3hr69Q49J0vvAZaCNR50WzpKfXa/cYpWw/X8) and [against JvdV's regex](https://tio.run/##XVG9TsMwEN7zFCeKZBuFisBWqUJtt4oVlqhFJrkkLokd2W6hI6xMvEM3XqATA0J9j/IiwfkpAiwP5/u@@@6@c7m2mZIXVaJVAcKitkrlBkRRKm2h1CpeRtZr0AXm@fqANI9bXPHcb2KRrL0O0pjiI3DjAs9reU4n1byAIRBCKv/682W3Ofp6ep@M99vNx9vudTq/2m@fK4eGweA0mHlejAk4dRFTwwYeuKPRLrWEOzcg1dgvuI0yqsmchqPxjF4G7CQcTWbs5Jj4hrFWgaca0fyXOOjCcPjLCP0zqw9h58sRZ04uURokCAmayxTpmQ9B4MM5G0APps1qjMqXVigJVouV4HVK4wIja0DFMeQoU5sZ3/FAuosYg1UQZRjdN9PVHR6Ujusm3eYpGY0nxHc6JXLr9ic7J/XpOZaQltY17CfLjXG/eHBOSH@hhGw5zkVbQW7qDXCLMWHVNw). (But, I neglected to check extremely unbalanced odd cases...) Checks that no more than half of the symbols in every prefix are `C` and that no more than half of the symbols in every suffix are `B`.

```
,U                  Pair the input with its reverse.
    "⁾CB            For the original and C, and the reverse and B:
  ċƤ                Count how many times the symbol occurs in each prefix.
        Ḥ           Double the counts.
         «Ƒ         Are all elements less than or equal to
           J        their 1-indices?
            >LḂ$    Also, reject any odd-length inputs.
```

Comment: I don’t know Jelly but from your description I don’t get how it accommodates concatenation.  For instance AACCBA.

Comment: @doug In `AACCBA`, the prefix `C` counts are 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, and the suffix `B` counts backwards are 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0. None of those are strictly greater than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, so it knows that there aren't so many of one or the other that the string can't possibly be balanced (if you treat `A` as something that can be arbitrarily made into a `B` or `C`).

Comment: But this a valid string as it’s the concatenation of AACC and BA.

Comment: @doug And it's properly accepted, since neither the Bs nor Cs are too "heavy".

Comment: Oh, fair enough.  I hadn't grokked your description.  I thought you were pairing stuff from the front with the back.  I'm not sure I get it still, but I'll ruminate on it.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 63 bytes

```
lambda x:bool(match('^([AB](?1)*[AC])*$',x))
from regex import*
```

See an online [demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY37XMSc5NSEhUqrJLy83M0chNLkjM01OM0oh2dYjXsDTW1oh2dYzW1VNR1KjQ1udKK8nMVilLTUysUMnML8otKtCDGbCgoyswr0UjTUHd0cnRW19SECC9YAKEB)

This is based on the *PCRE* regex pattern:

```
^([AB](?1)*[AC])*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7z1fFZ/1). I was unsure if we were allowed to simply post the pattern for 18 bytes.

---

## Excel (ms365), 120 bytes

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=REDUCE(A1,ROW(A:A),LAMBDA(a,b,IFERROR(REPLACE(a,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"AC","BA","BC"},a),"")),2,),SUBSTITUTE(a,"AA",))))=""
```

The idea here is to 1st replace any of the compound words that are not a copy of itself. If not found, try to replace 'AA'. Check if the final result after the last iteration is empty.

Comment: If you're any good with .NET regex, you could always do a Retina answer

Comment: ...Also erroneously rejects `AABA`, `AACACA`. `^([AB](?1)*[AC])*$` seems to work though.

Comment: "The empty string is considered a valid word in the language."

Comment: You can't hardcode the input into your program. However, you can submit a function like this: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3HXMSc5NSEhUqrJLy83M0ivVyE0uSMzSK1OM0oh2dYjXsDTW1oh2dYzW1VNR1KjQ1uTJzC_KLShSKUtNTKxQSixWKIQZtKCjKzCvRSNNQd3RydFbX1IQIL1gAoQE

Comment: You can also use a star import to save one byte: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3HXISc5NSEhUqrJLy83M0chNLkjM0itTjNKIdnWI17A01taIdnWM1tVTUdSo0NbnSivJzFYpS01MrFDJzC_KLSrQg5mwoKMrMK9FI01B3dHJ0VtfUhAgvWAChAQ

Comment: Building on @xigoi's suggestion: [another byte saved](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY37XMSc5NSEhUqrJLy83M0chNLkjM01OM0oh2dYjXsDTW1oh2dYzW1VNR1KjQ1udKK8nMVilLTUysUMnML8otKtCDGbCgoyswr0UjTUHd0cnRW19SECC9YAKEB)

Comment: @TheThonnu, not sure if done correctly (Python was merely a way to demonstrate the pattern). Thanks for thinking along. Both you and xigoi

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 55 bytes

```javascript
f=([x,...y],z)=>x?x<'C'&f(y,-~z)|x!='B'&z>0&f(y,~-z):!z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9NT8IwGMfv@xQPF9qStngGO9I2XjzowSOQ0MxOa8a2tJWMqXz1uREhzMuT/P5vyfNhDiZk3tWRldWr7bpc4HVDOefHLW2JSJtVc480mub4SNmpJd/NRCCFpm16d9ZOrCWLSdtFG2Jmgg0gYJdICYyxFKL/tIlWF8xNEQZW6paV1mNfS33LUl34PCe1HNWlHNlqnO7D@t/4qL3j0bs9JjzUhYsYbUpE@N7U2INIwf/J802YsVna3zkhy@T6LM8r/2Cyd4zXjoLdkqH0lQBkVRmqwvKiesM5dr0u4PHl@YnXxgeLLYEVoAOCBaAGURgi/e4PWXa/)

This question [can be solved in linear time](https://tio.run/##fVLbaoQwEH3vV0xTyiZ0191u3wQLSaD/IbsJWoJKEgv9ejvGWC@s@pQ5lzmTic2vL@rqo@vuSsNPbso7dSx9AvxKDUZVWMIrXOE5g0sKVvnWVvCVG6eCqMiNhmwUns9wDfCtbivPkXBJONIDP7CJEXNGzBk5Z2RkcJJo@xwCazuqB@DBYC8INSa/KdCldR5oMJ5iIwaEk4ODsvI1EEGCxWE2npPvusTbJK4xpaeoO8LSy1YB6IHcAaGorH2hrAslm7q6JGopao@9kk1IH4DiGSIjEvxGaY8tLqHQ/c0LHBvc8EjjegrIsr5vOujfMnj/55UJT6l9JE9L0qkH64vAEI7pXWNxV3T4Q4gUnBPGcAc6OFakEJukkHLHKbncJLkYSW/bNSf5diTn20ax0xR7yr1RF4ndHw), however we do prefer golf instead of time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
^((A|B)|(?<-2>A|C))*$(?(2)^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYkhDoAwEAR93wHJHQmmmkB2V/CLBgQCgyDI/v1ozWQm817f/Zwx2n5EMUOlV9uWOa@ocp8G2yx78QgRSCKZKDUTlMAOgQloxp6t1C9/) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^(
```

Starting at the beginning of the string, ...

```
(A|B)|
```

match either of `A` or `B`, or...

```
(?<-2>A|C)
```

... match a previously matched `A` or `B` with an `A` or `C`, removing the knowledge of the match, so that a subsequent `A` or `C` has to match a previous `A`or `B`, ...

```
)*$
```

... repeating until the end of the string, ...

```
(?(2)^)
```

without leaving any unmatched leading `A`s or `B`s.

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>125</s> 134 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)bool{l:=s
for _,e:=range[]string{"BA","AC","BC","AA"}{l=ReplaceAll(l,e,"")}
return l==""||l!=s&&f(l)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=1ZXBitRAEIaPYj9Fb8MuCWZEbxJooatUEDwsznEdNnHojIM9mSHJDMrsXH0JL4vgQ61nH8ROsurUv-pdBjKp1N_pn_qqK5-_LNbXNw825fx9ufB6VS5rpZarzbrpHppq1ZlfQds183W9M1-3XTV5cvPp6PmyXrRGVdt6rquk1eOT9O16HfYht62q1o2-zHxum7Je-IvZKNgbciYzjuOF-otz5rAP9rXfhHLuXQhJyHxmTHpQje-2Ta2DtcZcXYUT256dVUlID6Obb_e-D7v39pNU79U0t9NNWHZJoSeTyVPdNVuvmJwbw6oMbR8THcfELPPs-Dh29DMeXufYieXOiTRJdRQzvBxWs5BD8vjF0sRxRsjADst1JLYvMvOmNuktqVbnVg-s9DQWM_ThWM42M-OqqF3WmfZ9Klw8mmXx-nim_IdNdpnb87JpPUX-iU9VOe96VZUs67io0lFzYuPDvbp_HvugqxLzwr189fxZrovTtujz-elOR0X_FyNrx_voMBs2jZv06eFOW9vfp-oQf8rvfPOxexe7q9-yiEiOSxKjfxGLWakmUMsKOpZqRMZQb_f38t9pLSIn02CFCDpTeiHwQgyN62Qo1QxtLqvCYAX6Cs5QjEHOwjlJQgSEsIkdtDgcYEmInPRCgIgceJGMCBjBgSZgRDhNgBFJRgSMSDIihjMPXhgPt1TjYJN1AUYEjAgYsYO5CZDYOdAT6An0MAqBEwMnBk535zj4IfADpHDuM5BiAj-AiolxlON3gyAGPfgBXMz4qcDvEviRvAr1hzE-TO_f0zHTw7z_v4b77cf--nr8_wE)

Recursive function that repeatedly replaces the `A[empty string]B` pairs with an empty string.

#### Explanation, slightly ungolfed

```go
import."strings"      // boilerplate
func f(s string)bool{ // function that maps string -> bool
l:=s                  // init
for _,e:=range[]string{"BA","AC","BC","AA"}{
                      // replace these pairs in this exact order
l=ReplaceAll(l,e,"")} // with an empty string
return l==""||l!=s&&f(l)} // ok if empty, not ok if non-empty
```

#### Changelog

- +9 bytes for matching `AACC`, using a different approach.

Comment: This rejects empty string as an input, but I think that can be fixed by rearranging the return statement: `l==E||l!=s&&f(l)`. As a bonus, it's shorter, too.

Comment: Fails for `AACC`.

Comment: This submission is still invalid after the fix. Please stress test your code.

Comment: @HuỳnhTrầnKhanh Then can you provide some testcases that my solution fails for? I've thrown quite a few test cases at it now and can't find any problems.

Comment: To stress test, you can do [what Unrelated String did](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259012/). One test case you fail on among many is `AAAACCCC`. I recommend you don't attempt ad hoc fixes to patch individual test cases. Use stress testing instead to validate your program.

Comment: I noticed that you did a fix. You can do more stress testing on longer inputs, for example inputs of length 10.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„AB„ACâIgиæõδ.;õå
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8RycQ4Xx4kWf6hR2Hlx3eem6LnvXhrYeX/v/v5OzkDAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f9HDfMcnUCE8@FFnunWF3YcXnZ467ktetaHtx5e@l@HC6SaqzwjMydVoSg1MUUhM48rJZ9LQUE/v6BEH2IolEKzx0ZBBaw2L/W/k6OjM5eTs5Mzl6MTkOUI5jpBxYCiIHkgpQQGXM5OQOToCCScnIAqnIEsZ5AuZ0eghCNQnTOIBdTIBQA). The test suite contains a `;` (halve) after the `g` to speed it up substantially.

**Explanation:**

```python
„AB„ACâ     # Push ["AA","AC","BA","BC"] by taking the cartesian product of "AB" & "AC"
 Ig         # Push the length of the input-string
   и        # Repeat the earlier list of strings that many times as single list,
            # so each individual pair is repeated the input-length amount of times
    æ       # Get the powerset of this list
      δ     # Map over each inner list:
     õ .;   #  Replace every first occurrence of the pairs one by one with an empty
            #  string in the (implicit) input-string
         õå # Check if the resulting list contains an empty string
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Minor note: for an explicit empty string input, it'll do the following steps: `„AB„ACâIgи`=`[]` → `æ`=`[[]]` → `õδ.;`=`[""]` → `õå`=`1` (truthy). This is different than if no input is provided, since `õδ.;` would then keep `[[]]` and the result is falsey: [try it online with explicit empty string input](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8RycQ4Xx4kWf6hR22h5fZHt56boueNZA6vFTn/38lMAAA) vs [try it online without any input](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8RycQ4Xx4kWf6hR22h5fZHt56boueNZA6vFTn/38A).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
⊞υＳＦυＦABＦACＦ⌕Ａι⁺κλ⊞υΦι∧⁻ξμ⁻ξ⊕μ¬⌊υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7NCoMwDL77FMFTAt0TeOoEwcNGwScQ7WZZGkdtx96@qwPNJd9P8vFNyximdeScTdoWTAp6eac4xODkiURN9VgDYCL471pf6xO2B@yczJoZnQLDacOXAiYiOCI7x9GG3dYy481Jufkq8KTgJL1MwXor0c7oaZ@mMqVExPsa9x/nky89ip6z1m2bLx/@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υＳ
```

Start a breadth-first search with the input string.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over all of the found strings.

```
ＦABＦAC
```

Loop over `AB`, `AC`, `BA` and `BC`.

```
Ｆ⌕Ａι⁺κλ
```

Loop over all of the indices of those substrings in the string being considered.

```
⊞υΦι∧⁻ξμ⁻ξ⊕μ
```

Push the string with the substring at that index removed to the list of strings to consider.

```
¬⌊υ
```

See whether we were able to end up with the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 74 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRT8MgFIXf@yuufVghdma@1rEEeDJRX4xPy2JwwsRga4At3WZ/ewU6XTQlaUg/zj335Li1MKJvXt7l2sO90DUcs2wnLKgK3Wnnl/xN2FV5W3tMFqxpjBQ1EDiuhZPwDGQB3m5l1yuSEGqral8egha184IXE4XC7@U1xl@ovSAFKyaHxWyg00Bv0tCDNmnmQMis6wFepYKPkAUJu3EVUGvFfvnora43K1zBU619zJBBODthwEvno5ELNIZG6QUA5ZTmZUqIy1/GWaJKGPcXMzaCGeejak75CKYs4X8bKadj1pSOidmoRXDg4zHOzoniLF2qsYCQLkFimE/PDeFTbUNxVrqtiV0qpK98E7srYYZPis9QuDc10grQj5JEw3yXgwwbIW/D8uFpGOqy@GVd/w0)

```scala
f={case(x::y,z)=>(x<'C'&f(y,z+1))|(x!='B'&z>0&f(y,z-1));case(Nil,z)=>z==0}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBT8IwGMXv/BXPHaCNw@B1YSRtTybqxXgiHOrsoGZspi0EEP72@W0DUbNdtvy@1/e9vvlMF7quq7cPkwU8aVviazAA3k2OnGUr7XyCR@vDXNH3IsYhwUMZeAJZVYXRJVK0Kqx1yFZ0GPRk2hvskCTYI521CGA7TDFSIwyHZL0nK9zinnMcj83sJsVItsMDZpj8Uo0b1dX32RZkSjxNMSF8uuRdU3qm3ZISC@f0fv4SnC2XCwr7WtpASbt0W10gGB8aN0@0uR67hIyEiGIEtzE8/mFKtjTXhf@LpezBUqletRKqBwvZ4n8bhRJ91kL0iWWvBTmo/hhX55byQfvKKwfGbAzDMR1fG@Ln2rrinPGboukyZ/YuVE13MSb8rPikwkNRMpuDXZRpYxhtIxjaiGhHy7tRd@jU/cLToK6/AQ)

```scala
object Main {

  def f(chars: List[Char], z: Int): Boolean = chars match {
    case x :: y =>
      (x < 'C' && f(y, z + 1)) || (x != 'B' && z > 0 && f(y, z - 1))
    case Nil => z == 0
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val testcases = List(
      ("AA", true),
      ("CBAA", false),
      ("CBBB", false),
      ("BCCA", false),
      ("CCAC", false),
      ("ABAC", true),
      ("ACAB", false),
      ("AAAC", true),
      ("BBAC", true),
      ("CABC", false),
      ("CCAB", false)
    )

    for ((i, e) <- testcases) {
      val result = f(i.toList, 0)
      println(if (result == e) "v" else "x", result)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> <s>36</s> 29 bytes

```
~&/0{(0>)_,/x+/:1-2*&2 2\-y}/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxdjDsPgjAURvf7K+o14SE0LR2vCdg2DN3ZrEEGcXHCRzRGfrtoYkIdT853vp7GSMhnIsu0zcU9E1RwtYoUU54/XgJAgDVaM855yfrudD5MbMycjbWht9rOWZsfX4brhFYHudaBNuF6Gtu/86D24DZUtNGYuCqPUXiPabxYOkaS9t1wvLECoKEMGfrYQU0JfkNc4+cf00pQwxRAPfZxs5U7eAOesERh)

-2 bytes : Better lookup
-5 bytes : Even better thanks to @ngn
-7 bytes : Fairly sizeable overhaul by @ngn (go team ngn/k!!)